# How to troubleshoot udev not creating /dev/hda3 on gentoo boot?

Tags: linux, boot, hard-disk, gentoo, udev

My old gentoo laptop seem to have an issue with udev probably due to me updating software using `emerge`, upgrading udev+kernel, getting some messages "do these things after upgrading udev/kernel" and thinking "I'll look into the screen output, read those messages and take care of those things later before ever rebooting the system".  Unfortunately, being a bit in a hurry, I did, of course, forget to review those messages, shut down the machine, moved it physically to it's now location at home and started up, only to be greeted with a failure to find `/dev/hda3`.

Now I have managed to work around that (described in length below) by manually creating `/dev/hda3` and then making `init` continue the system boot but I need some advice on how to proceed on fixing this once and for all (so I don't have to repeat the procedure belown on every boot).

(If anyone can point to somewhere Gentoo machine where I can find all post-install messages for the packages I have installed, then I can find those instructions related to udev and the kernel which I should have read.)

Relevant software versions:

Gentoo-hardened-kernel 2.6.36-r6 (preferable) and 2.6.28-r9 (used for 21 months before shutdown). The cumbersome manual startup process described below has been verified to work for both kernel versions.
The udev package is udev-151-r4.

When booting up everything seems to be fine (the machine start's the kernel, it mounts /proc, /sys and /dev, starts udevd and populates /dev based on uevents, processes the uevents, mounts /dev/pts) until it comes to the step of 'Checking root filesystem'.

There it emits

`Failed to open the device '/dev/hda3': No such file or directory`

Then it asks me for root password (or Ctrl-D to continue).

I enter that, and in the shell, `mount` tells me that `rootfs` is mounted on and that `/dev/root` also is mounted on `/`.  Also, `mount` complains that `/etc/mtab` is not writable (e.g read/only filesystem).  All of this makes sense to me, given that the bootup is not completed.

Doing `ls /dev` reveals that there are no `hda`, `hda1`, `hda2` or `hda3` devices, which normally should be there (and which I would expect udev to create).  Also worth mentioning, `/dev` contains no `sda`, `sda1`, `sda2` or `sda3` devices either, so we are not seeing the issue of an updated udev or kernel changing it's convention of what to call different disk devices.  Neither is there any `/dev/disk` directory where disk devices could "hide".

So my next, potentially dirty, step is to manually create `hda`, `hda1`, `hda2` and `hda3` under `/dev` (I had a sneak peek at one of my other gentoo servers to figure out major and minor numbers as well as appropriate permissions and group membership):

`mknod /dev/hda b 3 0

mknod /dev/hda1 b 3 1

mknod /dev/hda2 b 3 2

mknod /dev/hda3 b 3 3

chmod 660 /dev/hda*

chgrp disk /dev/hda*`

Unfortunately, doing Ctrl-D or writing `exit` here will not continue the interrupted boot sequence, but instead it will initiate a reboot (which brings the machine up to the state of `/dev/hda` not found), so *that* path to solving this issue won't help, unfortunately.

Another workaround I tried (which failed) where to press 'I' (as well as trying 'i') as soon as `init` started and began to run the various init scripts (like mounting /proc, /sys and so on) but I never manage to enter interactive boot mode before the boot sequence reaches the (failed) attempt to check /dev/hda3.

Instead I continue with using my `/dev/hda3` device to mount my OS filesystem:
`mount -o remount -o rw /dev/hda3 /`

So, now I have write access to the file system of my machine which gives me *some* options regarding troubleshooting this situation: amending configuration files, starting various init-scripts and subsystems etc.

One thing that does *not* work is to change run-level though.  The reason is that `init 3` fails with the error message `init: /dev/initctl: No such file or directory`.  Again I do a sneak peek on my other Gentoo server and finds out that `/dev/initctl` is a pipe with permissions `600` and belonging to `root:root`, so I recreate that:

`mknod /dev/initctl p
chmod 600 /dev/initctl`

Now `init 3` fails, but a little differently; it hangs for a while and then gives up with the message `init: timeout opening/writing control channel /dev/initctl`.  This makes sense as the original `init` process (with process id 1) does not have this freshly created `/dev/initctl` opened for reading.

Now, reading the `init` man page I realize that sending `SIGUSR` will make `init` close and reopen `/dev/initctl`. *Exactly* what I need, so I execute the command `kill -l` to get a list of all signals and their number (in which I see that `SIGUSR1` has the number 10) then I issue the command
`kill -10 1`
to make `init` reopen `/dev/initctl`, then I retry entering run level 3:
`init 3`

Now `init` tries to enter runlevel 3 and executes a large number of scripts.  Unfortunately, all those scripts fails with `ERROR: cannot run syslog-ng until sysinit completes`.  So, I reboot the system (which now actually works as expected as I've made `init` listen to `/dev/initctl`: I logon as `root` and then issues `reboot`), repeats the above steps (except for remounting `/dev/hda3` as writable) up to and including the point of sending `SIGUSR1` to `init`.  Now I am trying to make `init` resume the boot sequence but in a more gentle way, by making it reread the `/etc/inittab` file:

`init q`

*Nothing* seem to have happened.  So, I'll investigate `/etc/inittab` where I find an entry for a runlevel which seem to called `sysinit`.  I take the risk and rerun that:

`init sysinit`

This time `init` complains with a usage message.  Reading `/etc/inittab` again, I see that the `sysinit` entry makes a call to `/sbin/rc` with the argument `sysinit`.  So, I decide to try *that*:

`/sbin/rc sysinit`

*Now* the system retries to boot up a number of services *and succeeds!*  Not only that, when re-running the init scripts for mounting `/proc`, `/sys` and `/dev` there is a check made to see if they already are mounted (a testament of how valuable it is to do sanity checks and error checks in code and act accordingly when running into exceptional circumstances). Happy with this, I decide to also run the commands for the `/etc/inittab` entry `bootwait`, as that one as well is missing a runlevel letter or digit.

`/sbin/rc boot`

Again, a number of init scripts are started, mainly for networking.  No unexpected errors are reported, so I'm happy to retry getting to runlevel 3:

`init 3`

Once the initscripts have finished, the machine is up and I can logon as root (and, in theory, fix the root cause of this mess)!

Comment: Do you have /dev/sda* entries? That should be the new names of your disk partitions.

Comment: @Keith: No, there are no /dev/sda* or /dev/sd* entries.  Not at the point when the boot sequence fails nor after I manually has managed to get the system to resume the boot process.

Comment: Tried to rebuild `udev` but got a warning that the kernel options `CONFIG_SYSFS_DEPRECATED`, `CONFIG_SYSFS_DEPRECATED_V2` and `CONFIG_IDE` was supposed to be disabled but still were configured in the kernel.  So, I'm rebuilding the kernel with those options disabled (and with ATA support enabled, so the kernel finds my drive partition).  Only thing is that this new kernel might call my root partition sda3 instead of hda3.  Well, I'll find out once the new kernel has been built (takes a while on a host from 1999).

Comment: Recompiling without CONFIG_SYSFS_DEPRECATED and CONFIG_SYSFS_DEPRECATED_V2 (but still with CONFIG_IDE and 'friends' set) resulted in a kernel which got a proper `/dev/hda3` device.  I cannot submit an answer for this yet, I have to wait for a few more hours before I do :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recompiled the kernel making sure that neither of `CONFIG_SYSFS_DEPRECATED` nor `CONFIG_SYSFS_DEPRECATED_V2` were set.

However, after a few retries with `CONFIG_IDE` not set (and a kernel which failed to find any harddrives), it turned out I had to `CONFIG_IDE` *set* as well as some more kernel config options found 'under' the deprecated ATA/ATAPI support.  Again, I had a sneak peak at that other server (which have properly working /dev/hda detection) and added the missing ATA/ATAPI related kernel options.  *Which* options I actually added I did not note, but here is the list of all the options activated underATA/ATAPI:
`CONFIG_IDE_GD

CONFIG_IDE_GD_ATA

CONFIG_IDE_PROC_FS

CONFIG_IDE_GENERIC

CONFIG_IDE_PCIBUS_ORDER

CONFIG_BLK_DEV_GENERIC

CONFIG_BLK_DEV_PIIX`

I also disabled the support for serial ATA and paralell ATA.

So *now* I have a kernel which boots up and successfully finds my `/dev/hda3` device.

I do know this is a bad practice, to rely on the deprecated ATA/ATAPI kernel support and *not* use the more modern SATA/PATA kernel support.  Eventually I have to migrate to SATA/PATA instead.   But for now, I'm happy (and a bit more knowledgeable about my Linux system).

(And my apologies if I post a question and then answers it and picks my own answer for being the accepted one.  Hopefully this answer/question still is a useful contribution to U&L)